# Maven Version Increment using github action

Tags: maven, github, github-actions, aws-codeartifact

I am writing to seek assistance with an issue I am experiencing while using the GitHub action "qcastel/github-actions-maven-release" to build my project. I have noticed that the action replaces my settings.xml file from the .m2 folder and uses its own settings file. This is causing issues with my build process as the required configuration for my private Maven repository in CodeArtifact is shows missing and it download from central repo.

I would appreciate it if you could provide me with some guidance on how to configure the action to use my own settings.xml file that contains the configuration for my private Maven repository in CodeArtifact.

Thank you for your time and assistance

I try by giving m2-folder-path, giving maven servers but also it picks the default settings.xml file from the /root/.m2 folder and try to find parent repo in central repository of maven.

```
  - name: Increment release version
    uses: qcastel/github-actions-maven-release@master
    env:
      JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/
      CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN: xxxx
    with:
      ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.GIT_ACTION_DEPLOY_SSH_PK }}
      skip-perform: true
      version-patch: true
      release-branch-name: "ET-1027_Package_Versioning"
      maven-servers: '[{"id": "xxxxx", "username": "aws", "password": "xxxx"}]'
      maven-args: "-Dmaven.repo.url=https://xxxx-xxxx.d.codeartifact.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/maven/prod/"
      m2-home-folder: '/home/runner/.m2'
```